# SVG image doesn't fix into bootstrap parent column div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, svg, bootstrap-4

I have a SVG inside CSS file. 
I would like it to be fitted inside column in a bootstrap div with col-lg-4. But it doesn't care about it. It should work as we apply img-fluid to the image so that it will automatically fit to its parent div. Now it doesn't care about it

```css
.star-rating {
  height: 90px;
  position: relative;
  width: 450px;
}

.star-rating:before {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHhtbG5zOnhsaW5rPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8xOTk5L3hsaW5rIiB2ZXJzaW9uPSIxLjAiIHg9IjBweCIgeT0iMHB4IiB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgNTAgNTAiIGZpbGw9IiM3ZjhjOGQiID4gICAgPHBhdGggZD0iTSAyNSAyLjI3MzQzNzUgTCAxOC42MDkzNzUgMTguNDgwNDY5IEwgMC44MTA1NDY4OCAxOS40MTc5NjkgTCAxNC42NDg0MzggMzAuNDEyMTA5IEwgMTAuMDcwMzEyIDQ3LjIyMjY1NiBMIDI1IDM3Ljc3MTQ4NCBMIDM5LjkyOTY4OCA0Ny4yMjI2NTYgTCAzNS4zNTE1NjIgMzAuNDEyMTA5IEwgNDkuMTg5NDUzIDE5LjQxNzk2OSBMIDMxLjM5MDYyNSAxOC40ODA0NjkgTCAyNSAyLjI3MzQzNzUgeiI+PC9wYXRoPjwvc3ZnPg==");
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-size: 90px;
  bottom: 0;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 90px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 450px;
}

.star-rating>span {
  display: block;
  text-indent: -10000px;
  width: 450px;
  height: 90px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.star-rating>span:before {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,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");
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-size: 90px;
  bottom: 0;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 90px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  text-indent: 10000px;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <div class="star-rating">
        <span style="width: 65%"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-8">
      Something something
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: do you have media queries?

Comment: No, this is all I have.

Comment: You probably need to adjust the `height`, `background-size`, and `max-width` based on media queries. I got something working by making the stars smaller here: https://codepen.io/nickfindley/pen/pqRvqP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>A lot of this solution is borrowed from [Bootstrap’s progress bar code](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/scss/_progress.scss) which makes use of flex to keep the progress bar in position inside its container.</s>

It turns out these parts weren’t actually doing anything!

I’ve added:

1. Set the height of `.star-rating` as 20% (one fifth) of its width
2. Set the `<span>` to match the height of its parent `.star-rating`
3. Add some top & bottom margin to complement bootstraps left & right padding

Additionally, I removed the `-sm` qualifier from your column classes and added some background color for clarity.

**Best viewed in *Full page*.**

```css
.star-rating {
  position: relative; /* 2 */
  height: 0;          /* 1 */
  padding-top: 20%;   /* 1 */
  margin: 5px 0;      /* 3 */
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,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");
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

.star-rating > span {
  position: absolute;       /* 2 */
  top: 0;                   /* 2 */
  bottom: 0;                /* 2 */
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,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");
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4" style="background-color: #7fff7f;">
      <div class="star-rating">
        <span style="width: 65%;"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-8" style="background-color: #ff7f7f;">
      Something something
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @SNaRe Note the update - previously the percentage width was displayed incorrect on smaller screen widths.